# Documentation for commands

Tags: documentation

Is there a way to view the documentation for a particular command.  Consider, as example `\NewDocumentCommand`.  Is it possible to find its description and synopsis ?

Comment: No, not in the sense you're asking. Packages and classes define commands and their documentation can be found in their respective documentations. Current kernel commands are documented in the places you already know about: `usrguide`, `clsguide` and `interface3`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\show\NewDocumentCommand
  
\end{document}
```

In the terminal and the *.log file you then obtain:

```
> \NewDocumentCommand=\protected\long macro:
#1#2#3->\__cmd_check_definable:nNT {#1}\NewDocumentCommand {\cs_if_exist:NTF #1
{\msg_error:nnxx {cmd}{command-already-defined}{\use:nnn \token_to_str:N #1{}}{
\token_to_str:N \NewDocumentCommand }}{\__cmd_declare_cmd:Nnn #1{#2}{#3}}}.
l.3 \show\NewDocumentCommand
```

Comment: I'm not sure this counts as documentation. It's the definition of the macro, but doesn't tell you anything more, and for complex commands is going to be quite un-understandable.

Comment: It also doesn't work for everything.

Comment: @cfr Certainly. I didn't call `\the` and so on.

Comment: Try `\show\textit` (for example).

Comment: @cfr \ShowCommand\textit